# Handling DB transaction in closure

Tags: php, pdo

I think DB transaction should be as small as possible, and close it soon.

So I wrote a helper function like ['using' statement in C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx).

```
function transaction($conn, $closure) {
    $conn->beginTransaction();
    try {
        $closure($conn);
        $conn->commit();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $conn->rollback();
        throw $e;
    }
}

$conn = new PDO('mysql:....');
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
transaction($conn, function($conn) {
    $conn->query('insert ....');
    $conn->query('insert ....');
});
```

but with this pattern:

- I have to capture manually any variables with `use()`
- Stack trace will be bit complicated

or, should I write try/catch and begin/commit in every transaction?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I think you should definitely begin and commit transactions when interacting with the database, instead of running it in auto-commit mode. I hope you get some great answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a couple of things I'd recommend you change about your current code, *and* there's an alternative to your using a closure's `use` construct to pass in other variables.

The first thing I'd do, is to change your function's signatures to type-hint the expected types for each argument, ie change the `transaction` function to look something more like this:

```
function transaction(PDO $conn, callable $closure)
{}
```

Optionally, replacing the `callable` type-hint with `Closure`. The upside of `callable` is that old-school callable constructs will be accepted, too (`array($object, 'someMethod')` or even `ucfirst`), the downside is, of course that functions like `ucfirst` are accepted, but clearly not a valid function in this context.

Anyway, apart from using `use` to pass in additional variables, you could add a third argument to the `transaction` function, and type-hint an array:

```
function transaction(PDO $conn, callable $closure, array $arguments = [])
{}
```

Then, simply invoke the `$closure` argument using `call_user_func_array` to pass the arguments that need to be passed:

```
array_unshift($conn, $arguments);//prepend $conn to the arguments 
call_user_func_array($closure, $arguments);
```

And you're there... Of course, if you find that `array_unshift` call clumsy looking (which it kind of is), you can just assume the `$arguments` array to contain the PDO connection from the off, in which case:

```
function transaction(callable $callback, array $arguments)
{
    if (!$arguments[0] instanceof PDO) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('arguments should contain PDO instance');
    }
    $conn = $arguments[0];
    try {
        $conn->beginTransaction();
        call_user_func_array($callback, $arguments);
        $conn->commit();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $conn->rollBack();
        throw $e;
    }
}
```

Again, there is a downside to this approach, the main disadvantages, IMO, are:

- Overhead (a PHP closure is syntactic sugar, it's actually creating a new instance of the `Closure` class.
- The `$arguments` array will often be a bit too complex for its own good, leaving you with code that actually calls your `transaction` function to decide on the actual logic -> every call can look different, and often will contain SQL strings, `fetch` calls and the like. Ugly code is harder to maintain...
- Like you said: the stack trace looses some of its relevance, making debugging harder.

The last two issues (code that is harder to maintain + harder to debug) are, to me, severe problems, so much so, that I'd recommend not to use the `transaction` function, but instead write the `try-catch` blocks where and when I need them.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't think an array parameter instead of `use()`, it's interesting! However, it seems to be tricky and usage is like as `use()`, so I'd prefer `use()`.